# Having trouble sending templates through WhatsApp Cloud API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I created a complete signup template with cloud API. I've put custom fields like name select date. template is approved and it's showing on my CRM. but when I sent this template I got an error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#131000) Something went wrong",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 131000,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "Something went wrong"
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "Ai9oDlQLfTBFgpIh748V1fO"
    }
}
```

but if I create a simple template and add a website button with my website link it works with no issue.

I need to send form message  using the WhatsApp template

Comment: You need to provide more information, it is not possible to detect what is the exact issue from error.

Comment: which information more I need to add here?

Comment: No one here has any superpower to see in your system what API you are executing, what is the request payload, what you have tried, and what is the debugging details. see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: I'm using Perfex CRM. but when I sent this template I got an error

`{
"error": {
"message": "(#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 132012,
"error_data": {
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"details": "header: Format mismatch, expected IMAGE, received UNKNOWN"
},
"fbtrace_id": "AuH3NdFu27pBdKYP76tU_1f"
}
}`

Comment: one more thing is when I create a template with a CTA button and add my website link then everything works fine. only issue is with when I create a template with fill form options.